# flutter don't catch error from node js api call with try and catch block, what am i doing wrong?

Tags: node.js, flutter, try-catch

the catch block is ignored even there's an error from the server
it's still executing the code in the try block!

simple flutter call to node js get request:

```
    void fetchData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/products/newProd');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      setState(() {
        _text = json.decode(response.body)['name'];
      });
    } catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

i produce an error in my node js code:

```
const newProd = async(req,res,next) =>{
try{
    if(1 + 1 === 2){
        throw new Error('error from server');
    }

    res.status(200).json({name : "test"});

}catch(err){
    next(err)
}

}
```

the response is good, but flutter do not catch the error, why what am i missing here, i am new to flutter??

Answer (score 0):

on flutter code on try use this:

```
void fetchData() async {
  final url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/products/newProd');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      setState(() {
        _text = json.decode(response.body)['name'];
      });
    } on Error catch (err) {
      print(err);
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting other status code rather than 200, it doesnt mean it is error. For example if status code is 400, you can handle it within try block,
in catch block u can handle if something wrong while fetching or parsing data

Answer (score 0):

So this is the code after i got the right answer:

```
 void fetchData() async {
    final url = Uri.parse('http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/products/newProd');
    try {
      final response = await http.get(url);
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        setState(() {
          _text = json.decode(response.body)['name'];
        });
      } else {
        print(json.decode(response.body)['message']); // printing the error from the server
      }
    } on Error catch (error) {
      print(error);
    }
  }
```